# How to check radiobox situation without a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i am designing a website. On the page there is a question with radiobox answers. I have 2 questions

1- I want to show another div that depends on the radiobox answer. Every radiobox needs to have different div target. Divs are hidden default, needs to show with radiobutton trigger.

2- Radiobox check is not gonna happen with a "confirm" button. I want to show the next div automatically when a radiobox is selected.

I think i need a check function but still cant make a working one. Help please

I tried something like this

```
function check() {
  document.getElementById("radiobutton").checked = true;
}
```

My main question div:

```
<div class="card">
      
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio1"><br>Text<p class="SecimAciklama">Text</p></div>
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio2"><br>Text<p class="SecimAciklama">Text</p></div>
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio2"><br>Text<p class="SecimAciklama">Text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>

  </div><!----card div--->
```

Comment: That should work. Show us your HTML.

Comment: would you clear more about your second question ...

Comment: I add my html main question div. I want to show one another div (from more hidden divs) when the user select a radio button.

Comment: Yes, i want only one selectable choice. Thats why i used it.

Comment: please clear about you second question ..

Comment: Why is this tagged as php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers, i finally did it! I know this is little but my js knowladge is zero.

```
<form>
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" onclick="CheckFunc()" id="Choice1" value="Radio 1"><br>TEXT<p class="SecimAciklama">TEXT</p></div>
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" onclick="CheckFunc()" id="Choice2" value="Radio 2"><br>TEXT<p class="SecimAciklama">TEXT</p></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
function CheckFunc(){
if(document.getElementById("Radio1").checked) {
document.getElementById("XXX").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("YYY").style.display = "none";
}else if(document.getElementById("Dizustu").checked) {
document.getElementById("YYY").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("XXX").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add an onclick event to your radio button input and then write a little function to show and hide your divs: (this could, of course, be simplified with jquery or something)

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" onclick="showContent(this, 1)" /> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" onclick="showContent(this, 2)" /> Option 2</label>

<div id="content1" style="display: none">Content for 1</div>
<div id="content2" style="display: none">Content for 2</div>

showContent(radioEle, id){
hideAll()
document.getElementById('content' + id).style.display = radioEle.checked ? 'block' : 'none'
}

hideAll(){
document.getElementById('content1').style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById('content2').style.display = 'none'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of javascript will add an event listener for input on your radio buttons and then you can do whatever you want when they are selected. If you show us the divs you are displaying, I could help with that as well.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".CoktanSecmeli").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    //select div and display it
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
      
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio1"><br>Text<p class="SecimAciklama">Text</p></div>
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio2"><br>Text<p class="SecimAciklama">Text</p></div>
<div class="col"><input class="CoktanSecmeli" type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio3"><br>Text<p class="SecimAciklama">Text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>

</div><!----card div--->
```